# Mobile browser unable to load the XML data from magento

Tags: android, .htaccess, rest, soap, magento-1.9

I am new to magento and android application develoment . My question here is that I am unable to load the XML data in android browser but with the same link i am able to display the xml data in Desktop browser .

These are the link i am trying

[for rest service](http://new.sporteemail.com/api/rest/products)

[for soap service](http://new.sporteemail.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl)

and both these links are related product retrieving from the magento site with respect to REST and SOAP service of magento.

Please help me